# converting hours to seconds in sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi is there any simple way to convert hours to seconds? by using sql query.

Ex: @mytime = 2:15 hours

expected output is @result = 8100 seconds.

2 * 3600 + 15 * 60 = 8100

Thanks

Comment: What's the context? Is this in a SQL select statement?

Comment: What is your current data type? Is it a string or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already presented the simplest way 8-)

If you want to convert hour string, then:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10) = '5:35'

SELECT 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@str, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @str, 1)-1) AS INT)*3600+
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(':', @str, 1)+1, 1000) AS INT)*60
```

Comment: Just I've another small issue here.. I'm passing float value to @str and I'm getting error. Any minor change need to do?

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way that works in SQL server and is less error prone.

```
DECLARE @str CHAR(5) = '02:15'
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', @str)
```